# TypeError: $(...).is not a function, how to execute the function after the jQuery plugin loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, assets

I load the jQuery plugin in the head,

Then run the function when DOM ready,

However, I always got the `TypeError: $(...).jSlots is not a function`

### index.html.haml

```
  %head
    = javascript_include_tag "application" 
    %script{charset: "utf-8", src: asset_path("jslot/jquery.jSlots.js"), type: "text/javascript"}
```

### jslot/jquery.jSlots.js

```
(function($){

    $.jSlots = function(el, options){
    ~~~
```

### index.js.coffescript

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('.fancy .slot').jSlots
      number : 1,
      winnerNumber : 1,
      spinner : '#playFancy',
      easing : 'easeOutSine',
      time : 7000,
      loops : 6,
      onStart:
        ->
          $('.slot').removeClass('winner')
      onWin:
        (winCount, winners) ->
          $.each winners, ->
            @addClass "winner"
            return
          if winCount==1
            console.log "hi"
          else if winCount > 1
            console.log "hi"
          return
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you aren't including jquery itself !

Try this :

```
%head
    = javascript_include_tag "application"         
    %script{charset: "utf-8", src: "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js", type: "text/javascript"}
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    %script{charset: "utf-8", src: asset_path("jslot/jquery.jSlots.js"), type: "text/javascript"}
```

I am not a ruby devlopper and do not use HAML, feel free to correct the answer.